Disabling touchpad buttons on Xorg
The physical buttons on my laptop's touchpad tend to get stuck. Is there a way to disable them without disabling the entire touchpad such that I can still move the pointer and scroll (and ideally but not necessarily use tap to click)?
I'm using linux (Xorg) on a HP Pavilion-15-cw1039nb.
